# Plotting a pseudo 3D globe

Tags: 3d, raycasting

I would like to plot a small globe where the main character can walk, exactly like Sonic & Knukles Bonus Stage. For those who won't google it, here is a [picture](https://images.app.goo.gl/X16ouk1UKnMPUi1SA).

I am familiar with Raycasting, used in Wolfenstein and other games to "simulate" a 3D perspective in a 2D map.

But I could not figure how to program the globe thing, and I suppose that it was not a real 3D rendering, as Sonic was a 16 bit game.

Any idea on how to do it without any sofisticated 3D engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overview**

- Set up an endless 1D track of 2x 2D planes. As you run forward, the plane behind you comes forward to keep you running; this keeps happening repeatedly whether you run forward or backward.
- Now do the same thing in 2D i.e with 2x2 2D planes. Wherever you go, the world continues beneath your feet.
- Transform the planes to a perspective view.
- Now create a spherical bulge effect through screen space transformation i.e. by adjusting all the ground pixels to make them appear curved, even though it's really flat, repeating surface.
- Even when the character [rotates 90 degrees](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fb8J09ARAk) over a few frames, this still shows the same curved-world effect.

**3D Planes in 2D**

Let's assume you have 2x2 flat planes rendering on your screen as squares (viewed top down), and you can move around on them as described above.

We now need to transform these planes (collectively), viewed top down, to an oblique-to-ground perspective.

This is done in 2 steps:

1. squeeze the combined ground plane so that its upper half "pinches" to the width of the viewport and its lower half exceeds the width of the viewport. This is done using `yRatio` as calculated in the code section below, i.e. the closer we are to the top, the more we scale `x` in order to pinch the top of the square so it looks like a frustum or triangle.
2. Scale it down and reposition it in y so that its bottom is flush with bottom of viewport, and its top is (say) at midway down the screen - this is your horizon.

Both of these steps are dependent on where the player is currently standing.

**Curvature**

A semicircle formula is needed for the transformation of pixels, which will be displaced along screen y to achieve the bulge effect. This part is left to your research.

```
semicircleDisplace(xCurrent)
{
    
    //formula to calculate maximal (horizon) yDisplacement from xCurrent
    //...
    
    return yDisplacement;
}

pixels[xCurrent][yCurrent].y += semicircleDisplace(xCurrent);
```

The problem with this is that we bulge *all* the pixels just as much near the bottom of the screen, as near the top, leading to a sort of upside-down U look to the terrain, when what we really want near the bottom of the screen is a nearly straight line; midway, some displacement / bulge; and at the horizon, maximal displacement. We achieve this by using a (possibly linear) interpolated factor:

```
semicircleDisplace(xCurrent, yCurrent)
{
    
    //formula to calculate maximal (horizon) yDisplacement from xCurrent
    //...

    //linear interpolation based on where we are between bottom of screen and horizon
    yRange  = yMax - yMin
    yRatio  = yCurrent - yMin
    yFactor = yRatio / yRange

    return yDisplacement * yFactor;

}
pixels[xCurrent][yCurrent].y += semicircleDisplace(xCurrent, yCurrent);
```

`yFactor` is a value between `0.0` and `1.0` by which you multiply `yDisplacement`. If linear interpolation (which is cheap) doesn't give a great look, you can play with non-linear interpolations to achieve the right sort of ground curvature look. But my guess is linear will look just fine.